# java Как использовать свой Comprator в TreeMap

Tags: java, коллекции

Допустим у меня есть класс `User` с полями `int id`, `String name`. Я добавляю эти объекты в `TreeMap`. По условию я считаю что ключ уникальности для `user` это `id`. Т.е. если в `TreeMap` есть юзер с `id = 1` и `name = Alex`, то при добавлении юзера с таким же `id` и новым именем, должна произойти замена. Для этого в классе `User` я сделал `implements Comparable` и переписал методы `hashCode()` и `equals()`. Все работает. Далее мне надо сделать сортировку по `name`, но при этом сохранить уникальность по `id`. Если я делаю свой `Comprator` в котором делаю сортировку по `name` и задаю его в конструкторе `TreeMap`, то уникальность слетает. В коллекции появляются два юзера с одинаковыми `id`.

Как сделать сортировку по имени, сохранив уникальность по id?

```
public class UserNameComparator implements Comparator<User> {

    @Override
    public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
        String name1 = o1.getName();
        String name2 = o2.getName();
        return name1.compareTo(name2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Класс `User` используется в `TreeMap` в качестве ключа?

Comment: Каким образов у двух юзеров с одинаковыми id оказались разные имена?

Comment: Это "учебная задача" чтобы понять как работает TreeMap. Я не понимаю просто почему не используется метод equals из User если я задаю в конструкторе TreeMap свой Comprator. Что происходит в этом случае?

Comment: TreeMap не использует при вставке equals() и hashCode(). Он использует compareTo() или Comparator.compare(), если задан компаратор. Это ведь дерево, причем сортированное. Поэтому вопрос о сортировке мне непонятен. В дереве у Вас уже отсортировано все по ключу используя указанные выше методы. Если нужно перестроить саму мапу, то вы передаете другой компаратор и заливаете туда элементы. Они сортируются по заданному вами компаратору.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде разобрался. Добавил в compare сравнение по id.

```
  @Override
public int compare(User o1, User o2) {

    if ((o1.getId() - o2.getId()) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    String name1 = o1.getName();
    String name2 = o2.getName();
    return name1.compareTo(name2);

}
```

Comment: Нет, так не получится: при разных именах TreeMap может просто не найти нужного юзера и ваше сравнение id не пройдет.

Comment: Как-то можно тогда решить используя TreeMap?

Comment: @АлександрАбрамов мне кажется правильней использовать в качестве ключа просто идентификатор пользователя, а в качестве значения уже сам объект

Comment: Для меня это "учебная задача", чтобы понять как работает TreeMap. Я просто тогда не понимаю, что происходит при задании своего Comprator в конструкторе TreeMap? Метод equals заданный в User уже не используется?

Comment: @АлександрАбрамов с чего бы он использовался если вы передали свой компаратор?

Comment: Т.е. если я использую свой компратор, то не могу переопределить метод equals так как мне надо?

Comment: В принципе можно использовать ваше решение с небольшими ограничениями: перед любым вызовом `put(user, ...)` нужно вызвать `remove(user, ...)`. И да: `(o1.getId() - o2.getId()) == 0` можно заменить на `o1.getId() == o2.getId()`.

Comment: Спасибо. Пойду разбираться как внутри устроено TreeMap

Comment: Получается HashSet и TreeSet по разному определяют "уникальность" внутри коллекции, хотя названия похожи. В случае hashset уникальность определяется по hashcode и equals. А в случае TreeSet через компратор? При этом получается некоторый "глюк" в TreeSet. Когда хешкоды равны у объектов, equals возвращает true. Но оба объекта в TreeSet.

Comment: Нет, немного не так. Вам нужно посмотреть на исходники TreeMap. У него есть поле что-то типа comparator, которое принимает компаратор, если Вы используете конструктор с компаратором. Если же нет, то это поле будет равно null и тогда при сравнении объектов будет вызываться метод compareTo() объектов, которые вы вставляете в мапу. Другими словами, если при создании мапы вы передаете компаратор, то будет использоваться его метод compare(), если же нет, то используется метод compareTo() объектов (мапа принимает только Comparable, вы же в курсе, да? Иначе получите ClassCastException)

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь усидеть на двух стульях - в качестве ключа вы используете и `id`, и `name` одновременно. Одна коллекция так делать не умеет, поэтому вам надо использовать две разные коллекции:

```
Map<Integer, User> usersById = new HashMap<Integer, User>();
Map<String, List<User>> usersByName = new TreeMap<String, List<User>>();

void putUser(User newUser) {
    User oldUser = usersById.put(newUser.getId());
    if (oldUser == newUser) return;

    if (oldUser != null) usersByName.get(oldUser.getName()).remove(oldUser);
    List<User> list = usersByName.get(newUser.getName());
    if (list == null) usersByName.put(newUser.getName(), list = new ArrayList<User>());
    list.add(newUser);
}
```

Comment: для этого подошла бы guava?

Comment: @Anastasiya ну, мультисловарь там вроде бы есть - но он тоже не двухключевой